# Capture html elements with selenium after clicking the search button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After clicking on the search button on the Homepage the giving results are shown on same page and the url is not changing at all. On the result page i am not able to find any html-elements.

this is what i try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    

# webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://homepage")

# click search
search_button = browser.find_element_by_name("searchButtonLabel")
search_button.click()

# click the element 
hit_list = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"keresgrid\"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/a/div").click()
```

and this is my error message:
no such element: Unable to locate element:

How can i read again the newpage(results) and find the html-elements?

thank you!

Comment: 2 Points: may be you need to add delay to synchronize with application after click on search button and then try to find elements. or your Xpath is incorrect. If possible share you HTML code of the application after click of search button. Also highlight which object you trying to identify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is Wait.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

hit_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='keresgrid']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/a/div"))
)
hit_list.click()
```

Comment: thanks! it worked with putting a delay of time.sleep(5) after search_button.click()

Comment: @patrik2017, If code works only with `time.sleep(5)`, then provided solution is not applicable and should not be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`browser.current_url` might be useful to make sure you're on the correct page.

You can also use `browser.page_source` to get the full HTML at the time you access it. You can use that HTML source to test your xpath query and/or make the sure page is as expected.